# Change entrypoint of a k8s Pod, but keep the CMD

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, command, docker-entrypoint

> *How to change the Docker `ENTRYPOINT` in a Kubernetes deployment, without changing also the Docker `CMD`?*

In the Pod I would do

```
image: "alpine"
entrypoint: "/myentrypoint"
```

but this overwrites either `ENTRYPOINT` ***and*** the `CMD` from the `Dockerfile`.

The [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) doesn't mention it, but seems like a big use-case missed.

Comment: Most cases of changing a container's entrypoint also reset the command; both [Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) and [`docker run --entrypoint`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime) also reset the command part.  Do you have a more specific use case where you want to reset the entrypoint (Kubernetes `command:`) but keep the command (Kubernetes `args:`)?

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT` is used whit `docker exec`, while `CMD` is the default with `docker run` when nothing is specified. I'm ok with the default `run` service (specified with `CMD`), `FROM` the image I am extending. But I want to customise its `ENTRYPOINT` script to handle specific `exec` commands.

Comment: I know I can use `command` together with `args`, but I do not want to manually keep in sync with the base image (that I have no control on). It's inconvenient when having: *BaseImageWithCMD -> MyBaseImage -> MyActualImage -> KubernetesWithCustomENTRYPOINT*

Comment: Both the entrypoint part and the command part are used when you start a container (concatenated into a single command with arguments).  Neither is used in either `docker exec` or `kubectl exec`.  Again, a more specific use case might help suggest a different approach.

Comment: My use case is to extend the entrypoint functionality, for when I use `kubectl exec` on the container running in the pod. I want to perform additional checks (that the base image entrypoint does not), when executing a non-default command,

Comment: *"Neither is used in either `docker exec` or `kubectl exec`"* - I was missing this detail and **wrongly expected** ENTRYPOINT to be called at every access to the container, as it happens with `docker run --rm -i ..`. I ended up adding it explicitly into `kubectl exec deploy/mint -- /myentrypoint $@`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a thing.

- `ENTRYPOINT` (in Dockerfile) is equal to `command:` (in PodSpec)
- `CMD` (in Dockerfile) equals `args:` (in PodSpec)

So just override `command` but not `args`.

Comment: If you check the notes, in the linked documentation above, there's written: *"If you supply a command **but no `args`** for a Container, **only the supplied command is used**. The default EntryPoint and the **default Cmd defined in the Docker image are ignored**."*

Comment: Yes, you need to restate the values but you don't need to change them.